# How to create pdf using array values in php

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf, fpdf

Hello everybody i am new fpdf. I have multiple array values and create a table.

```
$array1=[1,2,3];
$array2=['apple', "ball", "cat"];
```

I want to create a table using this values

```
Numbers Animals
1       Apple
2       Ball
3       Cat
```

I have tried this way but all values are printing one by one

```
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);

for ($i=0; $i < count($array1); $i++) { 
    [$pdf->MultiCell(30,12,$array1[$i],1), $pdf->MultiCell(30,12,$array2[$i],1)];
    }
$pdf->Output();
```

Can anyone suggestion me how this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);

$array1= array(1,2,3);
$array2= array('apple', "ball", "cat");

$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Numbers');
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Animals');
$pdf->Ln(10);
foreach($array1 as $key=>$row){
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,$row);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,$array2[$key]);
    $pdf->Ln(10);
}
$pdf->Output();
```

As `FPDF` examples you can uses `Cell()` for display values. And For the Line breaks use `Ln()`.
I assume both `$array1` and `array2` have similar number of elements. First two `Cells` use to display headings, then inside the loop display both values.

Comment: @user3099398. Thanks user3099398 It's working Perfect. I have small Doubt if i have more than 10 arrays it will print or not

Comment: If all arrays have same number of elements, Then you have to update headings and add 10 arrays like I did for $array2. Then it will print.

Comment: Thanks it's working Perfect. But I have 10 arrays with some values and all value are printing. But it is hidding some cell due to width. can we increase the width of the pdf like, A1, A3 to all values. Can you please guide me. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for you help. would please help me i have long heading like mini-Markdown formatting break into like mini-markdown and next line formatting.

Comment: How to bold for numbers,animals. and remaining things are normal

Comment: is there any way to reduce space between only first and second column